# Horizontal lines failing to plot

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

How can I draw a horizontal line at the price level when my condition is triggered ? (version#4)

```
plotshape(crossUp_red ? rvi : na, title="Up Arrow", style=shape.arrowup, location=location.abovebar, color=#109c3f, size=size.small, text="crossUp_red") // plots arrow
```

However I'm having trouble plotting a line at the price where 'crossUp_red' is triggered.

```
trigger_price = valuewhen(crossUp_red, close, 0)
plot(trigger_price, title="line_crossUp_red", color=color.green, linewidth=2, transp=0)
```

Draws line/all lines, but amassed at the bottom of the chart.

```
trigger_price = valuewhen(crossUp_red, close, 0)
hline(trigger_price, title="Trigger Price", color=color.red, linestyle=hline.style_dotted)
```

Error: Cannot call 'hline' with 'price'=series[float]. The argument should be of type: input float

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `line.new()` for this.

```
if (crossUp_red)
    red_line = line.new(bar_index, rvi, bar_index + 1, rvi, extend=extend.right)
```

This will draw a line and extend it to the right whenever `crossUp_red` is `true`. The line will be at `rvi`'s value. I don't know if it is price or not. If you want, you can change `rvi` to `close` then it would draw it at that bar's close price.

If you want to delete some lines in the future, you can use the `line.delete()` function.

Comment: thanks, exactly hat i was looking for..